# How to apply theorems for definitions with restrictions in coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I found a number of examples of definitions with restrictions in coq. Here is for example a variation of the `pred` function:

```
Lemma Lemma_NotZeroIsNotEqualToZero : ~ 0 <> 0.
Proof.
omega.
Qed.

Definition pred (s : { n : nat | n <> 0 }) : nat :=
    match s with
        | exist 0 pf => match (Lemma_NotZeroIsNotEqualToZero pf) with end
        | exist (S n') _ => n'
    end.
```

But I don't actually understand how to use this definition. Suppose I want to use `pred` for some natural number and I proved that this number is not zero. Like, for instance, suppose I proved the following lemma:

```
Lemma Lemma_TenIsNotEqualToZero : 10 <> 0.
Proof.
omega.
Qed.
```

Now, I want to compute what in essence is "`pred 10`" using `Lemma_TenIsNotEqualToZero`:

```
Eval compute in (pred ??).
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pred` is a function taking a `sig` type (try to `Print sig.`). Simply put, it's an inductive type with one constructor stating that "there exists an `x` of type `A` such that `P x` is true".

If you want to create a term of type `{n : nat | n <> 0}`, you will have to build it using constructors, like any other inductive type. In your case:

```
Eval compute in (pred (exist 10 Lemma_TenIsNotEqualToZero)).
```

It is the exact same syntax you used to pattern match on the `s` argument of `pred`.

Hope it helps,

V

PS: using `omega` for both your proofs is *really* overkill...

```
Lemma Lemma_NotZeroIsNotEqualToZero : ~ 0 <> 0.
Proof.
intro h.
apply h; reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma Lemma_TenIsNotEqualToZero : 10 <> 0.
Proof.
intro h.
discriminate h.
Qed.
```

Edit: `exists` takes 3 arguments in practice (use `Print` to get a clear idea what are they used for). Depending on the status of implicit types, you should write

```
exists _ 10 Lemma_TenIsNotEqualToZero
```

with the additional `_`.

Comment: That does not work. (I actually tried that before asking the question.) The error message is as follows: "Error: The term "10" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type "?641 -> Prop"."

Comment: Since you pattern matched using ``exists 0 pnf``, I though you had the automatic insertion of implicit type activated. Try with ``exists _ 10`` instead, it should work.